# Insufficient Privileges exception when calling DataCloud.FindDuplicates.findDuplicates

Tags: apex, permissions, duplicate-management, datacloud

For some users, calling `DataCloud.FindDuplicates.findDuplicates` throws an **Insufficient Privileges** exception.

It would appear to be a permissions issue but I have not been able to figure out what permission to grant to allow a user to call this method.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

API needs to be enabled in your org to use.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005140&type=1
Follow these steps and see if you can narrow down the issue.

1. If your org has already API enabled, check those user's Profiles and search for "API Enabled" and Tick that checkbox with Administrative permissions.
2. findDuplicates(sObjects), verify if user have Object and field level access for the sObjects being passed to findDuplicates()
3. Follow this article to check FLS and Object level access issues https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_insufficient_privileges_map.htm&type=5
4. Check if the user has access to DuplicateRecordItem and DuplicateRecordSet Objects. Both at Object and field level.
5. If you are using a Connected App, OAuth policies apply if the connected app is OAuth-enabled. The Permitted Users policy determines who can run the app. See if Permitted user policy is set to "All Users may self-authorize". Use this guide https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=connected_app_manage_edit.htm&type=5

Hopefully, this should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the user in question already has API enabled, so I guess that is not the issue it in my case

Comment: @JellevanGeuns, added additional debug checks.